# Generate block with many nested cases

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a module that contains an n x n grid of submodules, where each submodule is wired to its 4 neighbors in the grid. Each submodule looks roughly like this:

```
                 | up_in
                 V
           ____________
 left_in   |           |  right_out
---------> | submodule | --------->
           |___________|
                 |
                 | down_out
                 V
```

The submodules in the top/bottom row and leftmost/rightmost column must be wired differently from the rest because they're on the edge. Code like the following works fine but is very lengthy and full of repetition:

```
for (genvar row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) begin
    for (genvar col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) begin
        if (col == 0) begin
            if (row == 0) begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(special), .up_in(special), .right_out(normal), .down_out(normal))
            end else if (row < SIZE - 1) begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(special), .up_in(normal), .right_out(normal), .down_out(normal))
            end else begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(special), .up_in(normal), .right_out(normal), .down_out(special))
            end
        end else if (col < SIZE - 1) begin
            if (row == 0) begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(normal), .up_in(special), .right_out(normal), .down_out(normal))
            end else if (row < SIZE - 1) begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(normal), .up_in(normal), .right_out(normal), .down_out(normal))
            end else begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(normal), .up_in(normal), .right_out(normal), .down_out(special))
            end
        end else begin
            if (row == 0) begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(normal), .up_in(special), .right_out(special), .down_out(normal))
            end else if (row < SIZE - 1) begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(normal), .up_in(normal), .right_out(special), .down_out(normal))
            end else begin
                submodule sub(.left_in(normal), .up_in(normal), .right_out(special), .down_out(special))
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The submodule actually has more than 4 ports, so modifying the ports is slow and error-prone. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
for (genvar row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) begin
    for (genvar col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) begin
        submodule sub(
            .left_in(col == 0 ? special : normal),
            .up_in(row == 0 ? special : normal),
            .right_out(col == SIZE - 1 ? special : normal),
            .down_out(row == SIZE - 1 ? special : normal)
        );
    end
end
```

But this seems to not work because I don't think the ternaries are being evaluated at elaboration time--I think they're actually turning into muxes that persist in the design. Am I using the ternaries wrong, and is there some concise manner to generate this n x n grid of submodules?

Comment: A mux with a constant select should get optimized away. What makes you think it's still there after final optimization?

Comment: Vivado seems ok with ternaries for the input ports, but for some reason using a ternary on any output port gives `ERROR [VRFC 10-851]: illegal output port connection`

Comment: you cannot do it for output ports. you would need to assign it to a temp and then have a generated mux. there should be no mux in hardware. `.down_out(temp) ... if (col == SIZE-1) assign special = temp; else assign normal = temp;`

Comment: that worked, why don't ternaries work on the output ports?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify by first creating arrays for generic connectivity. The arrays need to be big enough to hold all of the connections, including the inputs and outputs.

```
//    vector                row     col
wire [WIDTH-1:0] leftright [SIZE]  [SIZE+1];
wire [WIDTH-1:0] updown    [SIZE+1][SIZE];

for( genvar row=0; row<SIZE; row=row+1) begin : r
  for( genvar col=0; col<SIZE; col=col+1) begin : c
    submodule #(WIDTH) sub(
      .left_in(leftright[row][col]),
      .up_in(updown[row][col]),
      .right_out(leftright[row][col+1]),
      .down_out(updown[row+1][col])
    );
  end
end
```

Now that you have an array linking the submodules, you can map the inputs and outputs to the array as desired. For example:

```
for( genvar i=0; i<SIZE; i++ ) begin : io_mapping
  // inputs
  assign leftright[i][0] = toplevel_left_in[i*WIDTH +: WIDTH];
  assign updown[0][i]    = toplevel_up_in[  i*WIDTH +: WIDTH];
  // outputs
  assign toplevel_right_out[i*WIDTH +: WIDTH] = leftright[i][SIZE];
  assign toplevel_down_out[ i*WIDTH +: WIDTH] = updown[SIZE][i]; 
end
```

---

Note: Verilog does not support 3+ dimensional arrays; SystemVerilog does. To work with Verilog, change:

```
//    vector                row     col
wire [WIDTH-1:0] leftright [SIZE]  [SIZE+1];
wire [WIDTH-1:0] updown    [SIZE+1][SIZE];
// ...
      .left_in(leftright[row][col]),
      .up_in(updown[row][col]),
      .right_out(leftright[row][col+1]),
      .down_out(updown[row+1][col])
// ...
```

to:

```
//    vector                    row     col
wire [WIDTH-1:0] leftright [0:( SIZE  *(SIZE+1)) -1];
wire [WIDTH-1:0] updown    [0:((SIZE+1)*SIZE   ) -1];
// ...
      .left_in(  leftright[    row*(SIZE+1) + col]),
      .up_in(    updown[       row*SIZE     + col]),
      .right_out(leftright[    row*(SIZE+1) + col+1]),
      .down_out( updown[   (row+1)*SIZE     + col])
// ...
```